# can I vertically center in body using flex with 100% height instead of 100vh?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to have the div centered in the body. It works if I change 100% to 100vh. I would like to avoid using 100vh as I want these rules to be usable within a container. Why does 100% expand the height for the background but not for the purposes of vertically centering the div?

```css
head + * {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #cb9800;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">This is vertically centered if I change 100% to 100vh</div>
```

Comment: `head + *` ? Rather odd. 100% of what? The parent height needs to be defined, therefore `html {height: 100%}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html, head + * {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #cb9800;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">This is vertically centered if I change 100% to 100vh</div>
```

```
    height: 100%;
```

You need to add height 100% to HTML tag also.

Comment: Thanks. I see now, the body tag's background fills the page regardless of its height.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    }
```